# How does back up data works in doing a restore factory in android device?

Tags: backup, factory-reset, restore, google-backup

Im planning to do a restore factory in my android device but I'm quite curious about this back-up data thing. How does it work? Does back up data means it will automatically restore my apps and other files after doing a restore factory setting (given there is a choice of auto restore).

*Edit by Izzy:* OP refers to *Google Cloud Backup*, as the link to a screenshot in the comments shows.

Comment: Where did you see this *back-up data thing*?

Comment: As t0mm13b indicates: You must be a little more specific on *which* "backup data thing" you are talking about. There are multiple of them, just see the [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info).

Comment: I dont actually know what kind of back up my device has. But I saw it on the reset menu . Here's a picture of it :  http://assets.cougar.nineentertainment.com.au/assets/TechLife/2013/01/11/Misc/android-privacy-settings.jpg

Comment: And one thing , Is it safe to do a restore factory in my device? Im worried that I might loss some of uninstallable apps. . Thanks (:

Comment: That's the *Google Cloud Backup* option. As far as known, it's 50% reliable (more precisely: backup seems to always work – everything else is questionable at best). So I wouldn't trust it bringing back your stuff, but rather investigate in one of the other solutions, even if only complementary.

Comment: Android has no way to backup your device. Some apps can choose to opt-in to saving some information. But if you do a factory reset you will lose the majority of your data, all saved  passwords, all apps, and most app settings.

Comment: I've just added the `google-backup` tag to your question. You will find some useful background information in [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-backup/info).